# props return undefined from NextJs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, ssg

I'm trying load an API response into a Next.js page but the props return undefined. I went through lot of answers from StackOverflow still couldn't find a solution to my problem.

Edited this post added a few more details for support.

Here is my code below.

**_app.tsx**

```
import 'tailwindcss/tailwind.css';
import '../styles/globals.css'
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import { UserProvider } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0';
import App from 'next/app';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
 return (
   <UserProvider>
   <Component {...pageProps} />
   </UserProvider>
  )
}

MyApp.getInitialProps = async (appContext) => {
 const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(appContext);
 return {...appProps};
}

export default MyApp
```

**profile.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { useUser } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0';
import withAuth from '../components/withAuth';
import { Navbar } from '../components/navbar'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'
import type { GetStaticProps, NextPage } from 'next';


export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async(context) =>{
   // const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/users`);
   const data = "sed"
   console.log(data);
   return {
      props: {
          users:data
      }
   }
}

const Profile: NextPage<{users:any}> = ({users}) => {
   const {user, isLoading} = useUser();
   console.log(users);
   return (
    <>
        <Navbar />
        <div className={styles.container}>
            <div>profile</div>
        </div>
    </>
   )
}

export default withAuth(Profile);
```

Here is the code for HOC that is wrapped for each page after login.

**withAuth.tsx**

```
import Login from "../pages/login";
import { Spinner } from "./spinner";

const withAuth = Component => {
const Auth = (props) => {
const { isLoggedIn, loading } = props;

    if(loading){
        return (
           <Spinner />
        )
    }
    if (!isLoggedIn) {
         return (
           <Login />
         );
    }

    // If user is logged in, return original component
    return (
      <Component {...props} />
    );
};

if (Component.getInitialProps) {
  Auth.getInitialProps = Component.getInitialProps;
}

   return Auth;
};

export default withAuth;
```

Comment: @juliomalves I have added the HOC.

Comment: I'm not able to replicate the issue - here's a [simplified codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-raman-d7n15?file=/pages/profile.js). Could you provide a [mre] where the issue occurs?

Comment: @juliomalves I realised without the HOC I am able to retrieve data. It's something that I have tweak in withAuth.tsx